# TestNG - providing parameters for class level test

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am running tests using TestNG, Java & Eclipse work-space.
I can run tests in a number of ways.
I can run a TestNG file, or I can run individual classes.
If I run from an individual class, the parameters are not picked up from the TestNG.xml file.
I may want to switch testings to a different URL.
This form, given in Tutorials, does not work, & only produces errors.

```
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ParameterizedTest1 {
   @Test
   @Parameters("myName")
   public void parameterTest(String myName) {
      System.out.println("Parameterized value is : " + myName);
   }
}
```

This is from a Tutorial at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_parameterized_test.htm

Error says this: [Utils] [ERROR] [Error] org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'url' is required by @Test on method addProjectTask but has not been marked @Optional or defined
in C:\Users\SStaple\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-38561327\testng-customsuite.xml

*** I called my parameter url. i.e:

```
@Test(groups = { "all", "projects", "create", "simple" })
@Parameters("url")
public void addProjectTask(String url) {
    System.out.println("Parameterized value is : " + url);
```

I don't want to have to re-code this every time I switch URL.

Testng.xml looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite allow-return-values="false" configfailurepolicy="skip"
    data-provider-thread-count="10" group-by-instances="false" guice-stage="DEVELOPMENT"
    junit="false" name="hardening-simple" parallel="none" preserve-order="true"
    skipfailedinvocationcounts="false" thread-count="5">
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
    <parameter name="url" value="https://url/#/" />
    <parameter name="printToFile" value="true" />
    <parameter name="trace" value="false" />
    <parameter name="opt" value="true" />
    <parameter name="customer" value="Demo" />
    <parameter name="network" value="NSG Designated Streets (Type 1/2)" />
    <parameter name="buildNo" value="025" />
    <parameter name="teamCity" value="false" />
    <parameter name="retest" value="0" />
    <parameter name="user" value="normal" />
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="listeners.TestNGCustomReportListener" />
    </listeners>
    <test allow-return-values="false" group-by-instances="false"
        junit="false" name="firefoxTest" preserve-order="true"
        skipfailedinvocationcounts="false">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
        <parameter name="url" value="https://url/#/" />
        <parameter name="opt" value="true" />
        <parameter name="user" value="normal" />
        <groups>
            <define name="simple">
                <include name="simple" />
            </define>
            <run>
                <include name="simple" />
                <exclude name="not-implemented" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
```

Does anyone know the correct method?

Answer (score 0):

These parameters are only picked up if the class is run from testng.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Using parameters is not a optimal solution. Drive your values from properties file, this way you can maintain all your data. You can create variables in your code and use the values from properties file. You can change the data in properties file without changing the code but in more manageable way. If there are more than one set of data, then you can use multiple properties file and just provide the address of the file.

Tutorial for properties file:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bljA8dpfWeQ

Comment: If you could add some clarity to this it would be more beneficial. Links are typically frowned on as they cannot be relied upon. Perhaps you could explain why your answer is better.